# Writing to two standard input pipes from C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process, console-application, stdin

I am using FFMPEG from my C# application to build out the video stream from raw unencoded frames. For just one input stream this is fairly straightforward:

```cs
var argumentBuilder = new List<string>();
argumentBuilder.Add("-loglevel panic");
argumentBuilder.Add("-f h264");
argumentBuilder.Add("-i pipe:");
argumentBuilder.Add("-c:v libx264");
argumentBuilder.Add("-bf 0");
argumentBuilder.Add("-pix_fmt yuv420p");
argumentBuilder.Add("-an");
argumentBuilder.Add(filename);

startInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", argumentBuilder.ToArray());

var _ffMpegProcess = new Process();
_ffMpegProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_ffMpegProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => { Debug.WriteLine(e.Data); };
_ffMpegProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => { Debug.WriteLine(e.Data); };

_ffMpegProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

Console.WriteLine($"[log] Starting write to {filename}...");

_ffMpegProcess.Start();
_ffMpegProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
_ffMpegProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < videoBuffer.Count; i++)
{
    _ffMpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(videoBuffer[i], 0, videoBuffer[i].Length);
}

_ffMpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
```

One of the challenges that I am trying to address is writing to two input pipes, similar to how I could do that from, say, Node.js, by referring to `pipe:4` or `pipe:5`. It *seems* that I can only write to standard input directly but not split it into "channels".

What's the approach to do this in C#?

Comment: To what end? You want ffmpeg to create two video streams in the output file?

Comment: You have to use `NamedPipeServerStream`... There are no examples about writing to multiple `NamedPipeServerStream`... [Here](https://mathewsachin.github.io/blog/2017/07/28/ffmpeg-pipe-csharp.html) it is suggested to write asynchronously...

Comment: @CaiusJard no, I want to merge the video and audio streams, which `ffmpeg` supports by separating the pipes. However, it doesn't seem like there is as easy of a way to do that as on other platforms.

Comment: Thank you @xanatos - that seems like the right way to go. I will explore that option and report back with the outcome. Feel free to post as answer to this question, so that I can flag it as such once I am done with the experiment (and you get the points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what is written [here](https://mathewsachin.github.io/blog/2017/07/28/ffmpeg-pipe-csharp.html) and on a good night of sleep (where I dreamt that I could use `Stream.CopyAsync`), this is the skeleton of the solution:

```
string pathToFFmpeg = @"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";

string[] inputs = new[] { "video.m4v", "audio.mp3" };

string output = "output2.mp4";

var npsss = new NamedPipeServerStream[inputs.Length];
var fss = new FileStream[inputs.Length];

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fss.Length; i++)
    {
        fss[i] = File.OpenRead(inputs[i]);
    }

    // We use Guid for pipeNames
    var pipeNames = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

    for (int i = 0; i < npsss.Length; i++)
    {
        npsss[i] = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeNames[i], PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    }

    string pipeNamesFFmpeg = string.Join(" ", pipeNames.Select(x => $@"-i \\.\pipe\{x}"));

    using (var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = pathToFFmpeg,
            Arguments = $@"-loglevel debug -y {pipeNamesFFmpeg} -c:v copy -c:a copy ""{output}""",
            UseShellExecute = false,
        }
    })
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FFMpeg path: {pathToFFmpeg}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Arguments: {proc.StartInfo.Arguments}");

        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.Start();

        var tasks = new Task[npsss.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < npsss.Length; i++)
        {
            var pipe = npsss[i];
            var fs = fss[i];

            pipe.WaitForConnection();

            tasks[i] = fs.CopyToAsync(pipe)
                // .ContinueWith(_ => pipe.FlushAsync()) // Flush does nothing on Pipes
                .ContinueWith(x => {
                    pipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    pipe.Disconnect();
                });
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
finally
{
    foreach (var fs in fss)
    {
        fs?.Dispose();
    }

    foreach (var npss in npsss)
    {
        npss?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There are various attention points:

- Not all formats are compatible with pipes. For example many .mp4 aren't, because they have their moov atom towards the end of the file, but ffmpeg needs it immediately, and pipes aren't searchable (ffmpeg can't go to the end of the pipe, read the moov atom and then go to the beginning of the pipe). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/479063/ffmpeg-pipe-input-error) for example
- I receive an error at the end of the streaming. The file seems to be correct. I don't know why. Some other persons signaled it but I haven't seen any explanation

  \.\pipe\55afc0c8e95f4a4c9cec5ae492bc518a: Invalid argument
  \.\pipe\92205c79c26a410aa46b9b35eb3bbff6: Invalid argument
- I don't normally use `Task` and `Async`, so I'm not 100% sure if what I wrote is correct. This code doesn't work for example:

  ```
  tasks[i] = pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync().ContinueWith(x => fs.CopyToAsync(pipe, 4096)).ContinueWith(...);
  ```

  Mmmmh perhaps the last can be solved:

  ```
  tasks[i] = ConnectAndCopyToPipe(fs, pipe);
  ```

  and then

  ```
  public static async Task ConnectAndCopyToPipe(FileStream fs, NamedPipeServerStream pipe)
  {
      await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync();
      await fs.CopyToAsync(pipe);
      // await fs.FlushAsync(); // Does nothing
      pipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
      pipe.Disconnect();
  }
  ```

Comment: I am flagging this as an answer because it does go _in the right direction_. Seems like `ffmpeg` does not play well with dual streams (MP4 video frames and AAC audio, at least), and every time I tried using this, it deadlocks or doesn't use a stream. I ended up encoding the video first, and then overlaying the audio with the help of another `ffmpeg` run. Thank you @xanatos for the pointer regarding named pipes - this was an "eureka" moment for me.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky As I wrote, there are problems with mp4 streams because their "header" is towards the end